# Unable to find variables to load database data into

Tags: android

I'm trying to [follow this tutorial.](https://dzone.com/articles/create-a-database-android-application-in-android-s). (Theres a lot of spelling mistakes which doesnt fill me with confidence).

Anyway I'm at the part where they speak about the `public void LoadStudents()` function.  They don't mention where to put it, but I'm assuming in the my `MainActivity.java` file, which now looks like this:

```
package com.chud37.myfirstdatabase;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void loadStudents(View view) {
        MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        lst.setText(dbHandler.loadHandler());
        studentid.setText("");
        studentname.setText("");
    }

}
```

I'm getting three errors when I build:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable lst
error: cannot find symbol variable studentid
error: cannot find symbol variable studentname
```

I dont understand why.  I've been following the tutorial as closely as possible up until this point.  The only thing outside of it that i've done is change my `app` file where it states 'beta01`to`alpha1` because otherwise I cannot use the GUI to add buttons and things, (thats a whole other error that I have no idea about at this point, I dont think it's affecting this).

My `activity_main.xml` file looks this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/studentid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Student ID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/studentname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Student Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/studentid" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnload"
        android:onClick="loadStudents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="LOAD DATA"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/studentname" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="ADD"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="383dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnfind"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="FIND"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btndelete"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnadd"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="383dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btndelete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DELETE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnupdate"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="383dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnupdate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text="UPDATE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="383dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lst"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="146dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnfind"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnload" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please help! Thanks

Comment: You might want to start with a different tutorial that mentions how to assign XML Views to Java variables

Comment: Also, `SQLiteOpenHelper` isn't really recommended for beginners. Please try https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your `views` into the `Activity` like

```
TextView lst = view.findViewById(R.id.lst);
```

add that line in the method `loadStudents`

Similarly add other views to your activity.